# Speeding up MySQL query by replacing IN() clause with JOIN or by other means?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is there any way to speed up the following `MySQL` query?

```
SELECT prop1, count(prop2) AS num_of_products FROM products 
WHERE insdate > CURDATE() AND 
    basecat='319' AND 
    prop2 NOT IN(SELECT number1 FROM categories WHERE basecat='319') AND 
    prop2 like '______%%' AND 
    accountcode IN(427,428,432,434,438,441,445,451,459,461) 
GROUP BY prop1;
```

Currently performance killer is a subquery in the `IN()` clause:

```
prop2 NOT IN(SELECT number1 FROM categories WHERE basecat='319')
```

I've tried my luck with `JOINS`:

```
SELECT prop1, count(prop2) AS num_of_products FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t_a.prop1, t_a.prop2 FROM products t_a 
    LEFT JOIN categories t_b 
        ON t_a.prop2 != t_b.number1 
        WHERE t_a.insdate > CURDATE() AND
        t_a.basecat ='319' AND 
        t_a.prop2 like '______%%' AND 
        t_a.accountcode IN(427,428,432,434,438,441,445,451,459,461)
) tmp_q
WHERE prop1 IN(427,428,432,434,438,441,445,451,459,461)
GROUP BY prop1;
```

This one is *~17x* quicker, but it produces inaccurate results, because the initial test `prop2 NOT IN(subquery)` is not really equivalent to the `t_a.prop2 != t_b.number1`.

Is there any other way to query database in the more intelligent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT prop1, count(prop2) AS num_of_products 
    FROM products AS t_a
    CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(number1) AS numbers
       FROM categories 
       WHERE basecat='319') AS t_b
    WHERE insdate > CURDATE() AND 
          basecat='319' AND     
          CONCAT(',', numbers, ',') NOT LIKE CONCAT('%,',t_a.prop2,',%') AND
          prop2 like '______%%' AND 
          accountcode IN(427,428,432,434,438,441,445,451,459,461) 
    GROUP BY prop1
) tmp_q
WHERE prop1 IN(427,428,432,434,438,441,445,451,459,461);
```

I doubt that the condition I added is sargable but you can give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution gives ~23x performance boost O_o. I've edited your answer to match my desired results.